# Setting a future day of repair depending on warranty selection

Tags: javascript, datetime, checkbox, selection

First of all I'm really new to Web Dev, just learnt basics of JS last week.

I have a project in which I have a VIP status, and 3 warranty types.
If the client is VIP -> fixing the issue will take up to 7 days.
Then I have 3 types of warranties - None, Regular, Extended.
None - up to a month of repair.
Regular - up to 3 weeks of repair.
Extended - up to 2 weeks of repair.

The solution must include ONLY javascript (no jQuery yet).
since the VIP checkbox isn't a part of the warranty selection, I'm having trouble connecting them.

In case my explanation confuses you - if the client is VIP - warranty options should be DISABLED. since it automatically gets a faster service.
if VIP checkbox isn't checked - I need to show the time of repair as shown above.

Thanks in advance

```
 <input type="checkbox" id="isVIP" />VIP?
```

```
<select name="warranty" id="warranty">
          <option disabled selected>Select warranty</option>
          <option value="none">None</option>
          <option value="regular">Regular</option>
          <option value="Extended">Extended</option>
```

Answer (score 0):

To achieve what you ask, you need to add some logic. It is hard to give you an answer since we don't have full context.

If I understand correctly, you want to be able to select a warranty if not a VIP.

To give you an idea, you can do this with javaScript :

```js
const checkbox = document.getElementById('isVIP');
const select = document.getElementById('warranty');

checkbox.addEventListener('change', () => {
  if (checkbox.checked) {
    // Disable options in select element
    for (let i = 0; i < select.options.length; i++) {
      select.options[i].disabled = true;
    }
  } else {
    // Enable options in select element
    for (let i = 0; i < select.options.length; i++) {
      select.options[i].disabled = false;
    }
  }
});
```

```html
 <input type="checkbox" id="isVIP" />VIP?
<select name="warranty" id="warranty">
          <option disabled selected>Select warranty</option>
          <option value="none">None</option>
          <option value="regular">Regular</option>
          <option value="Extended">Extended</option>
</select>
```

Hope it helps

Comment: This really helps.
Any idea on how to show the time-to-fix I mentioned?
My table tr>td injection looks like this:
 var tableData = document.getElementById("tableData");
  data = "";

  drones.map((item) => {
    data += `<tr>
    <td>${item.receiveDate.toDateString()}</td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td>${item.clientName}</td>
    <td>${item.clientPhone}</td>
    <td>${item.solutionDesc}</td>
    </tr>`;
  });
  tableData.innerHTML = data;
};